# Python - TypeError: set() missing 1 required positional argument: 'value'

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, windows-10, python-3.7

I am using a StringVar, however when I run the program it spits out the error:
TypeError: set() missing 1 required positional argument: 'value'

I have looked on here and other places on the internet and the same question is asked, however the solutions given don't apply. I haven't forgotten the brackets after StringVar, like all other questions.

```
save_theme_preference = StringVar()
save_theme_preference.set("default")

def dark_theme(): 
save_theme_preference = StringVar.set("dark")
```

Another function saves the value of save_theme_preference into a .txt file. However, whenever I run the dark_theme() function it spits out the error! Like I said, all other questions like this on the internet are missing the brackets after StringVar, thus all answers just point that out. I'm stuck, please help!

Comment: Did you mean `save_theme_preference.set("dark")`?

Comment: Unless `set` is marked `@staticmethod` you cannot call it directly off the `StringVar` class like that. You need to make an instance like you did above, then call the method off that instance.

Comment: This is not a complete example. Please provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think what you meant was:

```
def dark_theme(): 
  save_theme_preference.set("dark")
```

The error shows because you were calling `.set("dark")` on the StringVar class instead of on an object of that class.